# How can I take an existing animated GIF and make it play only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gif, animated-gif

I'm relatively new to Python. I have a large group of animated gif files which I need to change from looping forever, to playing only once.  Since I already know how to perform operations on multiple files using Python I'm halfway there.

So, is there a way to read the gif, change its setting and then save it?

I'm using python 3 FYI.

EDIT: Umm, if I did something wrong, please respond to let me know. Downvoting me into oblivion doesn't help me.

Comment: You're getting downvoted for not doing your own research (as the downvote arrow states "This question does not show any reesarch effort, is unclear or not useful"). A simple google query such as `python edit gif` would have led you to PIL, the python image library, which can manipulate most image files.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering! :)

I had been including 'loop' in my searches and nothing was turning up.  I was under the impression that PIL couldn't do that as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and the documentation in its parent library, PIL. Whether a GIF repeats is configured through the `Image.info['loop']` property.